unique indexes for multiple nan values in python list
Say I have the following python list with some random strings and multiple nan values:
l = [1, 'str', ',,,,', math.nan, 'another_str', math.nan, math.nan, 'last_str']

What I would like to achieve is a dictionary with the indexes of the elements in the aforementioned list as keys and the elements themselves as values, something that would look like this:
{0: 1,
 1: 'str',
 2: ',,,,',
 3: nan,
 4: 'another_str',
 5: nan
 6: nan
 7: 'last_str'}

The following code:
d_l = {}
for i in l:
    idx = l.index(i)
    print(idx, i)
    d_l[idx] = i

returns
0 1
1 str
2 ,,,,
3 nan
4 another_str
3 nan
3 nan
7 last_str

So we see that the index of the nan value has been 'recycled'. That's quite logical as the nan values are identical to one another.
In order to circumvent that, I tried to replace the nan values by unique strings:
d_l = {}
for i in l:
    idx = l.index(i)
    # check if i is nan, replace for unique str if that's the case
    if pd.isna(i):
        print(f"{i} is nan, index is {idx}")
        i = f"{idx} to be replaced"
    else:
        pass
    d_l[idx] = i

Which returns:
nan is nan, index is 3
nan is nan, index is 3
nan is nan, index is 3
{0: 1, 1: 'str', 2: ',,,,', 3: '3 to be replaced', 4: 'another_str', 7: 'last_str'}

I also replaced if pd.isna(i) by if el is np.nan, I got the exact same results though.

IIUC, you don't need to know what the items are to be able to create the key.
Simply enumerate them and pass to dict:
out = dict(enumerate(l))

Output:
{0: 1,
 1: 'str',
 2: ',,,,',
 3: nan,
 4: 'another_str',
 5: nan,
 6: nan,
 7: 'last_str'}


(way) simpler than what I thought
